# Difference between an instance of an empty class and an instance of object?

Tags: python, class, oop, object, methods

I created the following empty class `A` and an instance `a` of that class:

```
>>> class A:
...     pass
... 
>>> a = A()
```

As far as I understand, omitting base classes results in the class inheriting from `object`. I tried to verify this with:

```
>>> a.__class__.__bases__
(<class 'object'>,)
```

So I also created an instance of `object`:

```
>>> b = object()
```

However, comparing `a` and `b`, I noticed that using `dir` to get each objects attributes results in different lists for `a` and `b`:

```
>>> dir(a)
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__']
>>> dir(b)
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__']
```

`a` contains every attribute from `b` and an additional three more. The additional attributes only found in `a` are:

```
>>> set(dir(a)).difference(set(dir(b)))
{'__module__', '__dict__', '__weakref__'}
```

Where do they come from if class `A` is empty and inherits from `object`?

Comment: This is all Python 3, by the way.

Answer (score 2):

Even if `A` is empty, it is still a *user-defined* class, which has some distinct differences from `object` (a necessarily implementation-defined class).

Comment: Should this immediately clear things up?  Anyway, I'm sorry, I don't understand, unfortunately :( Isn't that just shifting the problem? Where does the difference between a user-defined class and a implementation-defined class come from, then? Where do the additional attributes come from?

Comment: They come from `type`. This isn't really something you need to worry about, unless you plan on writing your own Python implementation.

Comment: I don't worry, I'm just curious. ;) What do you mean, they come from `type`? Both `A` and `object` seem to be of the same class `type` and `type(A) is type(object)` returns `True`.

Comment: `type` is the metaclass that produces `A`, using `object` as the base class. `class A: pass` is equivalent to `A = type('A', (object,), {})`.